# How does this relationship between partial derivatives work?

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative, vector-analysis

Let $f$ be a scalar field then,

$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}(f \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_k}) = \frac{\partial }{\partial x_j} \frac{\partial }{\partial x_k}(\frac{1}{2}f^2)$.

How do you get from the LHS to the RHS?

I've tried applying the product rule to the LHS but I still couldn't arrive at the RHS. What am I missing?

Comment: Start with the RHS and note that $\partial_k(\frac12 f^2)=f\partial_kf$.

Comment: @user10354138 ah thank you!